# Changed root / file ownership, any way back?

Tags: linux, sudo, sudoers

I have made a typo and ran
`chown -R username /*` instead of `./*` as a root, and messed up everything.

Now, can't login as a root and change the ownerships back. Any way to repair without having to clean install?

I can login as user as well and did not change the owning group.

Output from sudo

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Comment: so as a general rule you shouldn't own any files outside of your home, so excluding it, you should be able to identify the files that were modified, but it may be difficult to identify what the correct user should be. in many cases, anything owned by someuser:root should probably be root:root, but I'd definitely write a script to check the current ownership before reassigning, so you don't touch unaffected files (I assume you canceled the chown before it changed every file) and only operates on files group-owned by root. don't try to just `chown -R` entire directory trees.

Answer (score 1):

The user who now "owns" all the files should now be able to access `/etc/shadow`, which contains all users and their setup, including the password hash. Edit `/etc/shadow` (eg `nano /etc/shadow`).
You will have something like this:

```
username:passwordhash:...
```

Copy your password hash (the second paramater, beginning with something like `$6$...` to replace the password hash for `root`, save the file and restart.

You can now log in as root and fix the `sudoers` file with:

```bsh
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
chown root:root /etc/sudoers
```

`sudo` should now work again (after a restart). Unless this is a fairly new install, there will still be plenty of other issues to deal with - but at least you have sudo now.

(Thank you, @Arjan, @Nikita Kipriyanov).

If that doesn't work:

From https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/sudo-etc-sudoers-is-owned-by-uid-1000-should-be-0-a-4175503030/

> Basically, your stuck.. So here's what you might want to do (please be
>   aware that I'm typing this from memory -- and some google to be sure
>   it's correct, however it might fail at some point):
>
> 1) Restart your computer..
>
> 2) On GRUB menu, press e to enter the editor mode
>
> 3) Use the arrow keys to navigate until the line that begins with "linux " and press e when on that line
>
> 4) Go to the end of the line and add the following: Code:
>
> `rw init=/bin/bash`
>
> 5) Press ENTER and b (or something of this sort) to boot the computer
>   with this settings... 6) After the computer booted into a teminal use
>   the following commands: Code:
>
> ```bsh
> chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
> chown root:root /etc/sudoers
> passwd root
> shutdown -r now
> ```
>
> The passwd command will ask you for a root password (just in case
>   something like this should happen again) The last command reboots your
>   computer.. After this you should be able to reuse commands starting
>   with sudo again..

Comment: As `/etc/sudoers` is currently owned by `username`, and the OP can log in using that user, I'd assume that user `username` could also simply run `chown root /etc/sudoers`? That would leave a zillion other files with the wrong owner though.

Comment: No, `username` shouldn't be able to do that because of: `chown: changing ownership of '/etc/sudoers': Operation not permitted`. Only superuser is able to change the owner-user of the file. Also, unprivileged user you can only change owner-group to that groups you belong to, i.e. to set owner-group to `root` `username` should be a member of a `root` group. Also /sbin/sudo got screved privileges, and it is normally suid executable. For it to work, one has to set it up root:root and also don't forget suid bit.

Comment: But, user should now have an access to /etc/shadow file. He is able to change (set) root password, by simply copying its own password-hash to the root's one. Then, login as root (in the text console, for instance, like Alt+Ctrl+F1) and fix things.

Comment: Ah, you're right @Nikita, I stand corrected, like indeed `man chown` also says _"For obvious security reasons, the ownership of a file may only be altered by a super-user."_